# 'ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED' when Inserting values from computer to another computer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-workbench

I'm using nodejs to insert new data to a database from my computer to another computer within the same network. But I'm getting the issue with the following details:

```
"code": "ER_HOST_NOT_PRIVILEGED",
"errno": 1130,
"sqlMessage": "Host 'xxxx-laptop.example.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server",
"fatal": true
```

I've already done the privilege configuration (which I'm not sure if I did it correctly). Here's my configuration:

```
CREATE USER 'sampleUsername'@'3000' IDENTIFIED BY 'samplePassword';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sampleUsername'@'3000' WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'sampleUsername'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'samplePassword';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sampleUsername'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Note: I did the said configuration in one of the Instance/Connection (homepage of mysql), on the SQL script file and ran it with 'ctrl' + 'enter' upon highlighting all.

Here is my code for the node.js:

```
var net = mysql.createPool({
      connectionLimit     : 50,
      host                : '192.168.1.20',
      user                : 'sampleUsername',
      password            : 'samplePassword',
      database            : 'test',
      dateStrings         : 'date',
      debug               : false,
      multipleStatements  : true
    });

net.query(sqlQry, function(error, resp){
  return callback(null, resp);
});
```

Where 'sqlQry' is the following:

```
var sqlQry = "INSERT INTO `tableSample` (FNAME, STATUS) VALUES ( 'JOHN', '1');";
```

This should be simple as adding new record in a database, but it seems doing it to another computer via network is a bit difficult due to this.